# How to get just inserted row from MySql to a php variable?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I'm using Zend Framework and MySql to create my web-application. My SQL-code is the following at the moment:

```
public static function newTestResult($testId, $accountId, $score, $deviation, $averageTime)
    {
        try
        {
            $db = self::conn();
            $statement = "INSERT INTO test_results(test_id, test_person_id, score, standard_deviation, average_answer_time, created_at)
                                        VALUES(" . $testId . ", " . $accountId . ", " . $score . ", " . $deviation . ", " . $averageTime . ", NOW())";
            $db->query($statement);
            $db->closeConnection();
        }
        catch(Zend_Db_Exception $e)
        {
            error_log($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Now what I'm asking is: How can I get the just inserted row to a variable in PHP? I would want to get my hands on the id-value what MySql is creating automatically for the row.

Here is my table code:

```
CREATE TABLE test_results(
id int UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
test_id int UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
test_person_id int UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
score float UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
standard_deviation float UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
average_answer_time float UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
removed boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
created_at datetime) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you the last insert id from the last query made.

```
$db->lastInsertId()
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the MySQL function "LAST_INSERT_ID()"

Comment: would be very userful if you could provide a link to the answer too.

Comment: Sorry about that, as fas as i know this is the same for every recent version of MySQL click on the [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) for documentation on the function.

Answer (score 2):

See also this forum for more detail on the methods available.
http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/188084-get-last-mysql-id-using-zend-frameworks/

In "plain" PHP, I usually use the mysql_ functions. The mysql_insert_id() function returns the key of the last row inserted. I'm not advocating this over using the Zend way, just giving context:

> mysql_query("INSERT INTO ... query");
>
> $id = mysql_insert_id();

Then reference that ID in writing other queries related to that inserted row.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$query="SELECT id FROM test_results WHERE test_id=$testId";
$id=$db->query($query);
```

I assume this is what you're looking for, otherwise you can change the WHERE condition to whatever you need.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it won't help me because the $testId is not unique value for different results, there can be many different results with the same $testId :(

Comment: Is there a function for example what would do SQL-INSERT and then return the just created row? :)

Answer (score 1):

From the MySQL manual: "If you insert a record into a table that contains an AUTO_INCREMENT column, you can obtain the value stored into that column by calling the mysql_insert_id() function."  This refers to the C function.

In the PHP manual, you are suggested to use the PDO function instead. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php `PDO::lastInsertId`

And apparently, "The insert() method on Zend_Db_Table will return the value of the last insert id." http://osdir.com/ml/php.zend.framework.db/2007-04/msg00055.html

Answer (score 0):

To get last two records from any table you can use the following query

```
SELECT * FROM aa WHERE ID IN(
    (SELECT  COUNT(*) FROM aa),
    (SELECT  COUNT(*) FROM aa)-1
)
```